# Multiple roles using @PreAuthorize

Tags: spring-security, jhipster

To check multiple roles has the method level access

I have used  @PreAuthorize annotation  to check the role

@PreAuthorize("hasRole(\"" + AuthoritiesConstants.USER + "\",)"  )

How to check multiple roles using @PreAuthorize annotaion?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can create a custom annotation to validate many roles and conditions. P.e.:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@PreAuthorize("hasRole(T(com.bs.dmsbox.api.constants.RoleConstants).ROLE_AGENT) " +
        "|| hasRole(T(com.bs.dmsbox.api.constants.RoleConstants).ROLE_ADMIN)" +
        "|| (hasRole(T(com.bs.dmsbox.api.constants.RoleConstants).ROLE_CUSTOMER) && #userId == principal.username)")
public @interface IsAuthenticatedAsAgentOrCustomerIsUserId {
}
```

Then, you can use this annotation as below:

```
@IsAuthenticatedAsAgentOrCustomerIsUserId
Folder findByUserIdAndType(@Param("userId") String userId, @Param("typeId") FolderType id);
```

This annotation validate that user logged as role AGENT or ADMIN. If user has role CUSTOMER validate if `userId` parameter is equals to user logged

Answer (score 34):

@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_USER')")

```
hasAnyRole() 

When you need to support multiple roles, you can use the hasAnyRole() expression.

@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ADMIN','DB-ADMIN')")
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html
https://www.appsdeveloperblog.com/spring-security-preauthorize-annotation-example/

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to include any piece of reference, advice and guidelines here. Code-only answers give a solution but not really an answer.

Answer (score 13):

Simply combine roles by using `&&` or `||` in SpEL expressions

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('" + AuthoritiesConstants.USER + "')" +
              " && hasRole('" + AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN + "')" )
```

Comment: How can we implement CustomPermissionEvaluator in jhipster?

Comment: That's a broad question. Since JHipster is based on Spring you should refer to Spring Security tutorial for details. Or search here at StackOverflow, it might be  already answered

Answer (score 1):

`SecurityExpressionOperations` interface in package `org.springframework.security.access.expression;` contains all the authorization-related methods.

Below are the most useful methods for authentication.

```
boolean hasRole(String role);
boolean hasAnyRole(String... roles)
boolean isAuthenticated();
boolean hasPermission(Object target, Object permission);
boolean hasPermission(Object targetId, String targetType, Object permission);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best option is to use @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole()")

In this case I suppose @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole(AuthoritiesConstants.USER, AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)")

Comment: `hasAnyRole` is not a method, you can't just pass `AuthoritiesConstants.USER` there, because than it will try to match with exact String like *"AuthoritiesConstants.USER"* instead of a `USER` field value of `AuthoritiesConstants` class