# Spring boot complex spel in @PreAuthorize

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-el

I'm trying to produce complex role model using custom annotation.
I have service roles: ADMIN, EMPLOYEE, ACCOUNTANT
And custom roles: 1_GET_DICTIONARIES, 2_WRITE_DICTIONARIES and so on...

I've read [a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57247649/multiple-roles-using-preauthorize) of custom annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority(#serviceRoles) " + || hasAuthority(#customerRoles")
public @interface IsAuthenticatedByServiceAndCustomRoles {
    []String serviceRoles;
    []String customRoles;
}
```

i need to annotate a controlelr with my annotation and pass two []String parameters to annotation, to be like this:

```
@IsAuthenticatedByServiceAndCustomRoles(
    serviceRoles = ['ADMIN', 'EMPLOYEE'], 
    customRoles = "['1_GET_DICTIONARIES', '2_WRITE_DICTIONARIES']")
```

but i can't properly pass my params to spel expression...
And the second problem, that i pass array to hasAuthority(), but it accepts single String role...

I don't understand how can i do this... Could anyone help me? please?

Comment: What do you mean by *i can't properly pass my params to spel expression*? You already did it.

Comment: And `hasAuthority` only accepts one parameter. You could try `hasAnyAuthority`.

Comment: When i set the mentioned above annotation on controller i receive authorities = String[1] "all elements are null" org.springframework.security.access.expression.SecurityExpressionRoot#hasAnyAuthority

Comment: How do you compile your code? Do you ise JDK >8 and the argument `-parameters`?

Comment: Yes, i'm on OpenJDK 11. I have a spring boot project... The current annotation impls is:

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target(ElementType.METHOD)
    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority(#serviceRoles) || 
    hasAnyAuthority(#customerRoles)")
    public @interface IsAuthenticatedByServiceAndCustomRoles {
        String[] serviceRoles() default "";
        String[] customRoles() default "";
    }

Comment: Could you add the stacktrace?

Comment: No exception is thrown.. i just get {String[1]@14352} at hasAnyAuthority(String... authorities) method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226576/discussion-between-bajiepka13-and-dur).