# Java Spring : how can I encapsulate annotations within an other annotation?

Tags: java, spring, automation, annotations, authorization

Is it possible to encapsulate an annotation within an other annotation with values?

I have a lot of end points on my `API` and would like to automate the required `roles / permissions` for the end point access.

Here is the current code :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/health")
public class HealthController {
    @GetMapping("/isAlive")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('ISALIVE', 'HEALTH_ENDPOINT')")
    public String isAlive() {
        return "Server is up and running";
    }

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('HELLO', 'HEALTH_ENDPOINT')")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

I have `2` authorities per end point, the first is the name of the mapping and method and the second is the name of the class.

In this example there is only `2` different end points with makes it easy but the finished product will have in the hundreds and doing all of the authorities by hand is going to be error-prone and not very efficient.

This is the desired result :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/health")
public class HealthController {
    @GetMapping("/isAlive")
    @MyAuthorisationAnnotation
    public String isAlive() {
        return "Server is up and running";
    }

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    @MyAuthorisationAnnotation
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

Where `@MyAuthorisationAnnotation` would give the right parameters to the `@PreAuthorize` annotation.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to encapsulate an annotation within an other annotation
> with values?

An annotation can have another annotation as a member.

```
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAuthorizationAnnotation {
   PreAuthorize value() default @PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('HELLO', 'HEALTH_ENDPOINT')"); 
}
```

However I don't think this helps. I am not familiar with Spring, but I think this post solves your problem, because it seems that `@PreAuthorize` can be applied to annotations so you can leverage transitivity if you use the checked annotation in a method.

[Solution's Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57252449/15659398)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What do you mean by transitivity ? I don't see how I can use this to be flexible ( as in : using the class name and method as parameters ). I must add, I am not certain if what I am trying to do can be achieved this way, I may have to look for alternatives such as custom filters ( Spring Security )

Comment: What I mean by transitivity is validating the method by validating the custom annotation that applies to that method. Below is the answer I was referring to:

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57252449/15659398)

Comment: thank you. Looks like I have some digging to do