# How to check if the user has any of the roles using @PreAuthorize

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, azure, azure-active-directory

I followed the article, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-active-directory and created an App role

with hasAuthority, I could validate a single role. However, I want to allow the user who is either an Admin or has Contributor permission. I tried with hasRole annotation as suggested in [Multiple roles using @PreAuthorize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57247649/multiple-roles-using-preauthorize).

```
//  @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('APPROLE_Admin')")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('Admin')")
    @GetMapping("/tutorials")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Tutorial>> getAllTutorials(@RequestParam(required = false) String title) {
        try {
            List<Tutorial> tutorials = new ArrayList<Tutorial>();
```

But it throws the following error

[image]

**Update: 24/05/2022**

This code is working

```
 @PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('APPROLE_Admin', 'APPROLE_Contributor')")
```

But the below code is throwing an error

```
 //@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_Admin')")
 //@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('Admin', 'Contributor')")
 //@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ROLE_Admin', 'ROLE_Contributor')")
```

**Logs:**

```
[nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/api/tutorials", parameters={}
[nio-8080-exec-5] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.bezkoder.spring.mssql.controller.TutorialController#getAllTutorials(String)
[nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Failed to complete request: org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
[nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
[nio-8080-exec-5] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
[nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, text/html;q=0.8]
[nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 403
```

Comment: What's the error in logs? Set debug=true

Comment: I am running the following command - mvn clean compile package spring-boot:run, where to set debug=true?

Comment: In application.properties or the configuration file you are using

Comment: @Mugil Karthikeyan, did you also try to use @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('Admin', 'Contributor')")?

Comment: @ChetanAhirrao - I have updated the question, can you check and suggest?